# Show the image of this function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Show that the image of the function (no derivative)

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x+1}{x}$$
is:
$$(-\infty,-1]\cup[3,\infty)$$

I tried to prove that it was increasing range and decreasing in others (maximum and minimum , without derivative), but I had problems to prove it.

For example:    $a < b$ (from $-1$ to $-\infty$)

$a^2b + ab + a < ab^2 + ba +b$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y =\dfrac{x^2+x+1}{x}$. Then $x^2+x(1-y)+1=0$. This equation has a solution if $(1-y)^2-4 \ge 0$ which gives $y^2-2y-3\ge 0$

Hence $(y-3)(y+1) \ge 0$. Hence $ y \in (-\infty,-1] \cup[3, \infty)$